# Path-connectedness in the language of category theory?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, definition, connectedness, path-connected

A non-empty topological space $X$ is connected iff the functor $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Top}}(X,-)$ preserves all coproducts. Is there a similar category-theoretic characterization of a (non-empty) path-connected topological space?

Comment: The zero-th homotopy "group" $\pi_0(X)$ is the set of path connected components of $X$ and can be defined categorially by the coequalizer of two ending points morphism $\mathrm{Hom}([0,1],X) \to \mathrm{Hom}(\bullet,X)$

Comment: What do you mean by "ending points morphism"?

Comment: The interval has the boundary consisting of two points $0,1$ and for every path $f:[0,1]\to X$ you get two points $f(0),f(1)$.

Comment: @AlexeyDo you could post your comments as an Answer unedited

Answer (score 3):

Denote by $\bullet$ any one-point space, then you have two maps (of sets)
$$\mathrm{ev}_i: \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Top}}([0,1],X) \longrightarrow \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Top}}(\bullet,X) = X \ \ \ \ f \longmapsto (\bullet \longmapsto f(i))$$
for any topological space, where $i=0$ or $1$. Let me consider the coequalizer of these two maps, we denote by $\pi_0(X)$ this coequalizer. In the category of sets, coequalizer of two maps is the quotient of the codomain by the smallest equivalence relation that "patching" two given maps. That being said, the coequalizer of the maps above is
$$\pi_0(X) = X/(\mathrm{ev}_0(f) \sim \mathrm{ev}_1(f)) \ (f:[0,1] \longrightarrow X).$$
which is simply $X$ mod out by the relation that two points are equivalent iff there exists a path between them. Therefore it is trivial iff for every two points, there exists a path connecting them, and this is the definition of a path-connected space.

Hence, $X$ is path-connected iff $\pi_0(X)=\bullet$ (or $1$) and moreover, from the very definition, $\pi_0$ is a functor from $\mathbf{Top}$ to $\mathbf{Sets}$.

Comment: You should write $1$ for the one-point set.

Comment: @ZhenLin May I ask why?

Comment: Because $0$ conventionally means the initial object, which has 0 points here.

Comment: That does not convince me. Usually, people denote by $\emptyset$ and $\ast$ for initial objects and final objects. You use $0$ only when your category is pointed or abelian.

Comment: Well, is $\textbf{Set}$ pointed or abelian?

Comment: No, that's why I use something different.

Comment: So why do you write $0$ for the one point set?

Comment: As I gave in my comment before (with the OP), it is a "homotopy group", so writing $\pi_0(X)=0$ is to remind that $\pi_0$ lies in a sequence of homotopy groups which are abelian for dimension $\geq 2$.

Comment: It is, in fact, not a group. It is not even pointed. Why use $0$?

Comment: Ok at this point I accept that I should write $\pi_0(X)=1$ (or maybe $\bullet$) (the same for $\pi_1(X)=1$ if you wonder) but for one-point space in $\mathbf{Top}$, I keep my notation unchanged.